# face alignment with hog features

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, svm, opencv3.0

I want to do face alignment with hog features. I have some landmarks from different part of a face like eyes, nose, mouth, ... . to compute features, I want to use **cv2.HOGDescriptor** and **hog.compute**.

for computing features around the landmarks, I should pass the location to **compute** and there is a part of it. Also, another problem is that I should reduce the window size around the landmarks for better accuracy.

first, I want to know by passing the locations to **compute** it will just extract features around it or no?

second, How should I reduce the window size?

third, Is there another function for doing this?

forth, How can I do training in this matter?